# Is there any way to trick std::make_shared into using default initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

You are expected to use `std::make_shared` to ensure that block with counters is stored next to data. Unfortunately internally `std::make_shared<T>` uses zero initialization for `T` (i.e. uses `T()` to initialize data block). Is there any way to trick it into using default initialization? I know I can use `std::shared_ptr<T>( new T, [](auto p){delete p;})`, but I'll end up with two allocations here (data and counter blocks won't be next to each other).

Comment: default initialization of `T` is `T()`. `new T` is same to `new T()`. Also, there is no need in specifying default deleter. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: make a wrapper of T with a constructor that does default initialization

Comment: @AndreiR. No, that is incorrect. `T()` is value initialization, and that can make a difference.

Comment: @AndreiR. : None of that is true beginning with C++03.

Comment: sorry, forgot to add "for non-trivial types (structs/classes)"

Comment: @AndreiR. also applies to structs and classes (which are the same thing.) It depends mainly on whether the type has a user declared default constructor.

Comment: @Andrei R. No, "new T" is not the same as "new T()"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a derived class to enforce trivial construction.

```
struct D : T {
    D() {} // Non-trivial constructor. Default-initialize T, which may be trivial.
};
```

Construct the derived class but assign it to the shared pointer you want.

```
std::shared_ptr< T > p = std::make_shared< D >();
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/g/z4TYm3)

Note that this is type-safe with respect to the destructor. `shared_ptr` always performs type erasure and uses dynamic dispatch before the destructor call, even for simple POD objects.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Genius... I have no idea how I didn't come up with this.

Comment: Yeah... Type erasure is something I don't really appreciate in std::shared_ptr. But I deal with large old codebase that has like 4 different homegrown smart pointers -- regardless how you look at it std::shared_ptr is better than any of them :-)

Comment: Yum: `template<class...Args> ListInit(Args&&...args):T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}{}`

Comment: @Yakk Use inheriting constructors. (Edit: Or just don't construct the derived class for cases of nontrivial construction. It's a bit of a corner case that trivial constructors are allowed to overload user-defined ones…)

Comment: even better solution -- [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345175/avoiding-extra-move-in-make-unique-make-shared-emplace-etc-for-structures-that-u)!