# Avoiding extra move in make_unique/make_shared/emplace/etc for structures that use aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, c++17

`std::make_unique()` (and similar functions) have a little [problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d4063069bcca194):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct S
{
    S()         { printf("ctor\n"); }
    ~S()        { printf("dtor\n"); }
    S(S const&) { printf("cctor\n"); }
    S(S&&)      { printf("mctor\n"); }
};

S foo() { return S(); }

int main()
{
    {
        printf("--------------- case 1 ---------------\n");
        unique_ptr<S> s1 = make_unique<S>( foo() );
    }

    {
        printf("--------------- case 2 ---------------\n");
        unique_ptr<S> s2 { new S( foo() ) };
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--------------- case 1 ---------------
ctor
mctor
dtor
dtor
--------------- case 2 ---------------
ctor
dtor
```

As you see we have an extra move that can be avoided. [Same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/242db546828a40f2) problem exists with `emplace()` in optional/variant/etc -- if object gets returned by other function, you have to move it.

This can be [addressed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb9f008ff76a53b7) with a trick:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <optional>

using namespace std;

struct S
{
    S()         { printf("ctor\n"); }
    ~S()        { printf("dtor\n"); }
    S(S const&) { printf("cctor\n"); }
    S(S&&)      { printf("mctor\n"); }

    template<class F, enable_if_t<is_same_v<invoke_result_t<F>, S>>...>
    S(F&& f) : S(forward<F>(f)()) {}
};

S foo() { return S(); }

int main()
{
    optional<S> s;
    s.emplace( []{ return foo(); } );
}
```

This avoids unnecessary move (enable_if hides constructor unless `f()` returns an instance of S). You effectively end up constructing your values inside of `std::variant`/`std::optional`/etc via a call to your constructing function.

This fix has a little problem -- adding a constructor breaks aggregate initialization. See [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e941d4788396acdc). I.e. if given structure had no constructor and you add one -- you can no longer initialize it like this:

```
struct D
{
    float m;
    S s;

    // adding new constructor here will break existing bar() functions
};

D bar() { /*...lots of code with multiple return statements...*/ return {2.0, foo()}; }
```

Question: Is there a way around this problem? Something that doesn't introduce new constructors...

I'd like to be able to efficiently put my structures into optional/variant/shared_ptr-block/etc without breaking (rather non-trivial) code that creates them.

---

**Edit**: All MSVC versions can't handle exceptions escaping from Barry's `factory`. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62841404/looks-like-is-nothrow-constructible-v-is-broken-in-msvc-am-i-wrong).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of adding a constructor to your type that takes a factory function, instead create a new external factory object with a conversion operator to your type. With C++17, that takes minimal work:

```
template <class F>
struct factory {
    F f;

    operator invoke_result_t<F&>() { return f(); }
};

template <class F>
factory(F ) -> factory<F>;
```

For your earlier example, `S` doesn't need the constrained constructor anymore. You would instead do:

```
optional<S> s;
s.emplace( factory{[]{ return foo(); }} ); // or really just factory{foo}
```

Which prints just `ctor` and `dtor`. Since we're not modifying `S` in any way, we could use this in aggregates as well - like `D`.

Comment: There may be a tiny marginal benefit to having `&`, `const&` and `&&`  overloads to your `operator result`.  Note that there is a small flaw in this, in that a greedy ctor to result could consume factory without giving the conversion operator a chance, but on aggregates that isn't a problem.

Comment: `invoke_result_t<F&>` (or `return std::move(f)();`, your pick.)

Comment: @Barry -- marvelous! Besides that little potential conflict between type's ctor and factory's operator (which can be easily worked around with magic ctor) I can't find any fault with this solution :).

Comment: @T.C. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Is it possible to use `decltype(auto)` in conversion operator?

Comment: @Orient Yes it is.

Comment: @Barry Maybe is it more expressive in the case above? If it is equivalent to `invoke_result_t< F & >`

Comment: @Barry Can you explain what T.C. meant in his comment? Why?

Comment: @C.M. `invoke_result_t<F>` is the result of invoking an rvalue of type `F` with no arguments. But the body is `f()`, which is invoking an lvalue. Hence, either fix the return type (to use `F&`) or fix the body to use an rvalue (`std::move(f)()`).

Comment: @Barry deduction guide doesn't work with MSVC2017 and GCC8.2 -- looks like it wants a ctor in `struct factory` :/

Comment: @C.M. I don't know which version 2017 is, but it does work on [gcc 8.2 and msvc 19.14](https://godbolt.org/z/3S07bK)?

Comment: @Barry [Here is](https://godbolt.org/z/AVUfxg) a dried out code that refuses to compile for me. godbolt can't compile it either. As of now I still have no idea what is wrong with it.

Comment: @C.M. Well, what's different between what you're doing and what my answer says? It's not the same.

Comment: @Barry It is precisely the same code you provided. I thought it simply doesn't work until you showed me your sample. Now I am trying to figure out why my code doesn't compile and (tbh) I am at a loss right now... Thought maybe you could see smth I missed

Comment: oh, crap... I see it. Braces instead of parenthesis. Duh!

Comment: @Barry Alas, all MSVC versions below 19.20 [can't handle this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62841404/looks-like-is-nothrow-constructible-v-is-broken-in-msvc-am-i-wrong). :\

Comment: @Barry my hands are sore from writing `data.emplace( inplacer{ [&]{ return ...; } } );` all over the code. We need `template<class F> inplace[_back](F&)` family of member functions in STL... :-/