# Looks like is_nothrow_constructible_v() is broken in MSVC, am I wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

**Edit:** [Here is](https://godbolt.org/z/KzEjsM) better code to reproduce. All MSVC versions below 19.20 fail to compile the test.

---

This problem is related to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345175/avoiding-extra-move-in-make-unique-make-shared-emplace-etc-for-structures-that-u). I've noticed my app getting terminated when logic under `inplacer` throws an exception.

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
#include <optional>

struct S{};
S foo() { throw "oh, noes..."; }

template<class F>
struct inplacer
{
    F f_;
    operator std::invoke_result_t<F&>() { return f_(); }
};

template<class F> inplacer(F) -> inplacer<F>;


int main()
try
{
    std::optional<S> v;
    v.emplace( inplacer{ []{ return foo(); } } );
    return 0;
}
catch(...) { return 1; }
```

If I build this with MSVC v15.9.20 and run it -- process gets `std::terminate()`d. Looks like the problem is in `_Construct_in_place()`:

```
template<class _Ty,
    class... _Types> inline
    void _Construct_in_place(_Ty& _Obj, _Types&&... _Args)
        _NOEXCEPT_COND(is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Ty, _Types...>)                     <----- HERE???
    {   // invoke True Placement New to initialize the referenced object with _Args...
    ::new (const_cast<void *>(static_cast<const volatile void *>(_STD addressof(_Obj))))
        _Ty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
    }

// std::_Construct_in_place<S,inplacer<S <lambda>(void) > >(S & _Obj, inplacer<S <lambda>(void) > && <_Args_0>)
```

It looks like `is_nothrow_constructible_v<S, inplacer<...>>` produces false positive which leads to `noexcept` declaration, which in turn kills my app when underlying code throws.

P.S. GCC and Clang seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [known bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/395024/-is-nothrow-constructible-intrinsic-doesnt-account.html). Fixed in msvc v19.16.