# C++11: most efficient way to append a POD to a vector<>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, emplace

Say I have a little structure with an `int`, `double`, and `std:string`.

I have a `vector` of these structures.

The efficient C solution would be to allocate the array, then loop through and set the field's values.  Each value is only calculated once and is stored where its final resting place is.

In C++11 I can use `emplace_back()` to avoid creating a temporary structure on the stack then copying it into the vector memory, and deleting the temporary structure.  But I'm providing a brace-enclosed initializer list to `emplace_back()` and compiler complains there's no matching function for call to `emplace_back` with a brace-enclosed initializer list.

So must I write a three-argument public constructor in this case?  And if I did so would it be as efficient as the C version?

Comment: Why `{}`? `emplace_back` takes a variadic number of arguments, so you can do `emplace_back(i, d, s);` Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question. Can you show the code you have an issue with?

Comment: Do you mean an aggregate? (instead of POD)

Comment: Something containing a non-POD like `std::string` is not a POD either.

Comment: Like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ab5q6E). It is C++17, but you can easily adapt it to C++11. Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345175/avoiding-extra-move-in-make-unique-make-shared-emplace-etc-for-structures-that-u)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention *structure* instead of *class*, and since you also mention C, I suspect you have not defined a constructor.

With `emplace_back` you still construct something; you do it in place, but you do it. So you need to provide the constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int i, double d, std::string s) : i(i), d(d), s(s) {};
    int i;
    double d;
    std::string s;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> v;
    v.emplace_back(1,2.5,"hello");
    std::cout << v[0].i << ' '
              << v[0].d << ' '
              << v[0].s << ' ';
}
```